# ¿Cómo hacer para que una búsqueda de mongo me devuelva los id de acuerdo al orden de un array?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

estoy teniendo problemas con el orden en me devuelve la búsqueda de mongo.

```
Post.find({ _id: { $in: userFound.favs } })
```

Basicamente en userFound.favs tengo un array con los ids de los posts favoritos del usuario, en este array los ids estan en el orden de acuerdo se fueron agregando.

El problema es que la búsqueda (.find) no me devuelve en el orden en el que estaban los ids del array sino que aplica otro orden.

Este seria el orden que tengo en el array userFound.favs:

```
[ new ObjectId("63feda62a3a366e275c616cf"), new ObjectId("63feda62a3a366e275c616d5"), new ObjectId("63feda62a3a366e275c616cd") ]
```

Este es el orden que me arroja la búsqueda:

```
[ _id: ObjectId("63feda62a3a366e275c616cd"), _id: ObjectId("63feda62a3a366e275c616cf"), _id: ObjectId("63feda62a3a366e275c616d5") ]
```

¿Cómo hago para que la búsqueda me devuelva los id de acuerdo al orden del array?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando lo que estás realizando y que si o si quieres conservar el orden de userFound.favs, lo más recomendado es ordenarlo una vez llegan tus objetos.

Para esto haré uso del método .map() de la siguiente manera:

```
const response = Post.find({ _id: { $in: userFound.favs } });
const responseOrdered = userFound.favs.map( id => response.find(r => r._id === id));
```

El resultado obtenido en responseOrdered conservará el orden de 'userFound.favs'.

Extra: También te recomiendo la utilización del método '.lean()' en tus consultas para mejorar el performance de tus consultas. Te dejo un enlace a la documentación respecto a este método y sus ventajas: [Enlace a la documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)